# How to solve err 'dict' object has no attribute 'save' when trying to make an update on DB

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting a problem working with django and its model system. I'm new working with django and I'm stuck since I've probably making the things wrong.

I'm trying to make an update to my DB and I get this error:

"'dict' object has no attribute 'save'"

I'm only trying to set a field to be active or inactive depending on a check input on my html.

I'm sending the right value on the request.

I'm getting a dictionary instead of a model object, but I don't really know how to change this, I think I followed the django docs. step by step.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class Flags(models.Model):
    num = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    deliver= models.CharField(max_length=1, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table ="FLAGS"
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from Logistic.models import Flags

def updateDisponibilidad(request):
    flag = request.GET.get("flag")
    print(flag)
    disp = Flags.objects.using('default').values('num', 'deliver').get(num__exact=1)
    print(disp)
    disp['deliver'] = str(flag)
    disp.save()
    return HttpResponse(disponibilidad)
```

Django docs. says I can acces to the values putting (in this case) disp.deliver, but when I do that, i get a different error:

'dict' object has no attribute 'deliver'

It would be fantastic if anyone can help me so I be able to use this code:

```
disp.deliver = flag
disp.save()
```

And work with that.

Comment: Why do you use `.values()` here?

Comment: The DB is firebird and I don't really know why I need to put .values() but if I don't I got this error: ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -206\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -206\n- Column unknown\n- FLAGS.ID\n- At line 1, column 1', -206, 335544569)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `.values()` in your query, if you want to obtain a `Flags` object, you should remove that, so:

```
def updateDisponibilidad(request):
    flag = request.GET.get("flag")
    disp = Flags.objects.using('default').get(num=1)  # no .values()
    print(disp)
    disp['deliver'] = str(flag)
    disp.save()
    return HttpResponse(disponibilidad)
```

If you use `.values()`, you retrieve a dictionary. Here we retrieve a `Flags` object, and model objects have a `.save()` method to update the object in the database.

If you want to render the content to a JSON response, you should use a [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), not use Django ORM features for that.

Furthermore if you update entities, one typically uses a POST, PUT, PATCH, etc. request, not a GET request.

Comment: Thanks so much, now I understand why I'm not getting a Flags object.  Then can you help me with this? If I delete the [.values()] I get a SQL error   <('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -206\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -206\n- Column unknown\n- FLAGS.ID\n- At line 1, column 1', -206, 335544569) >   And I don't understand why or where did I put the FLAGS.ID in my code or in DB, i created that table with only the two fields I'm going to use.

Comment: @ArielDlz: Django creates a primary key named `id` if you do not create a primary key yourself, after all the fields you specify are attributes, but you need a primary key to "address" an object.

Comment: @ArielDlz: you can let Django create the table, by using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/ If you do it manually, you will need to add an `id` yourself.